# is there any way to control request url on basis of routes in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a question about codeigniter: how to restrict url when the user enters 
    any url so that the first access goes to routes rather than controller, similar to how laravel works. Access goes to routes and than from routes access come to controller.

I want to know if there is a similar functionality (like with laravel) in codeigniter. Is this possible in codeigniter to access router directly
    rather the contoller?

Comment: You could try Luthier-CI add-on. https://github.com/ingeniasoftware/luthier-ci

Comment: if someone hits the URL then control goes to route directly or it will go to controller.